# Bootstrap .btn-group-justified in a .form-horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to experiment with using the `btn-group-justified` class in bootstrap to make a pair of buttons take up the entire parent width. Despite my code looking nearly identical to the example I was following, my page looked totally wrong, as if the buttons had a width of 0. After experimenting a bit, I discovered that the problem seemed to be that the buttons were with a `form-horizontal` class. I tried out this code to isolate the problem:

```
<form>
    <div class='form-group btn-group btn-group-justified' data-toggle='buttons'>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg active'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='1' /> Option 1
        </label>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='2' /> Option 2
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
<form class='form-horizontal'>
    <div class='form-group btn-group btn-group-justified' data-toggle='buttons'>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg active'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='1' /> Option 1
        </label>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='2' /> Option 2
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hozz2bvL/)

It looks like indeed the `form-horizontal` is the problem, but the weird thing is that using the Inspect Element browser feature, I cannot determine what is causing this. In my inspector, I see no selectors containing `form-horizontal` for the offending buttons.

Can anyone shed some light on why this happens? Is there a reason that the `btn-group-justified` class should not be used within a `form-horizontal` or is this a bug?

Comment: Inspecting the element shows that `btn-group-justified > .btn` is being set to `width: 1%;` by bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: @TylerH But that is true of the working buttons as well. It is not specific to `form-horizontal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form-group should not be there as a class of form-horizontal form's div

Here is what it should look like:

```
<form class='form-horizontal'>
    <div class='btn-group btn-group-justified' data-toggle='buttons'>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg active'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='1' />Option 1</label>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='2' />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `form-horizontal` class is set on the wrong element. When set to the child div of second form as such: `<div class='form-horizontal form-group btn-group btn-group-justified' data-toggle='buttons'>` it replicated the appearance from the first form as you intended. This is a styling of the `form-group` buttons, not of the `form` parent element.

Comment: I disagree. `form-horizontal` *is* for styling the `form` element. See the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Comment: You're correct bytesized, thanks. Ran a quick test, and it appeared to reach the same outcome despite the docs.

Answer (score 0):

your [**form-horizontal**](http://jsfiddle.net/hozz2bvL/1/)

```
<div class='form form-horizontal' data-toggle='buttons'>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg active'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='1' />Option 1</label>
        <label class='btn btn-default btn-lg'>
            <input type='radio' name='option' value='2' />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Justified button groups**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified):

> To use justified button groups with `<button>` elements, you must wrap each button in a button group. Most browsers don't properly apply our CSS for justification to `<button>` elements, but since we support button dropdowns, we can work around that.

[**Horizontal form**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal):

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the form (which doesn't have to be a `<form>`). Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row.

Comment: I see that it works, but I do not understand why. Could you elaborate?